# Single sign on as alternative - Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure-active-directory, single-sign-on

We have a website that has its own register/login logic. The user table, passwords...

As a business requirement, we need to integrate a 3rd party website, seamlessly to our users. So when a logged-in user clicks on the 3rd party's link he should be logged in straight away and has passed user details.

The 3rd party website supports single sign-on, and ideally, we would like to use Azure AD B2C to implement SSO.

Is it possible to keep Azure AD as an alternative place of login? So we still register a user via our website, use our login, but when a user comes to the other website he logins via Azure AD. Basically, this would imply pinging Azure AD via Rest API whenever we have a new user and passing his details there, but also somehow asking Azure AD to do the login verification with us using a REST API on our side

Is this achievable, or there is a better way of implementing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is a way you can follow I have design it as well in the below picture. From this way it can be achievable

Step 1: Store the new user in data base that is signup in website1.

Step 2: Export the user list in CSV format.

Step 3:  Upload the CSV file to storage account and the WebJob will be reading it to create users into the B2C directory.

Step 4 : if any new user comes for login in 3rd party website it will redirect to website 1 for register and if existing user comes it will prompt for Azure ad B2C authentication.

[image]

Please follow this document to implement the above scenario:
https://blog.kloud.com.au/2018/10/30/bulk-import-users-into-azure-ad-b2c-tenant-with-custom-attributes/

Comment: Thank you so much, but when a user comes to Website 2 and tries to log in if the pass is stored in Website 1 database how it can be auth by Azure AD B2C

Also is the import step necessary? If I have one by one user registered to Website 1 is it possible to pass it via API or Azure AD B2C doesn't offer this?

Really appreciate your input

Comment: It will auth directly from Azure AD B2C because all the user that is Signup in website 1 is moved to Azure AD B2C with the help of importing data from storage to Azure AD b2c. using API it not possible but using data base connection string from database to storage it possible and from there it can import to azure ad b2c.

Comment: I understand this but how do you handle passwords. If a user is registered on website 1 and you store his password in the database of website1 (encrypted), what do you send to Azure AD B2C?